# Php SoapVar - remove <SOAP-ENC:Struct>

Tags: php, xml, soap

I have some issues with an xml created with SoapVar in PHP.

I need to create an xml like this :

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
...
<ns2:Items>
    <ns2:OrderItem> 
        <ns2:ArticleID>242</ns2:ArticleID>
        <ns2:Properties/>
        <ns2:Quantity>1</ns2:Quantity>
    </ns2:OrderItem>
    <ns2:OrderItem> 
        <ns2:ArticleID>1256</ns2:ArticleID>
        <ns2:Properties/>
        <ns2:Quantity>1</ns2:Quantity>
    </ns2:OrderItem>
</ns2:Items>
```

But when I use SoapVar to create my node with this code :

```
// multiple articles
$orderItems = array();
foreach ($order->getArticles() as $article) {
    $art = new stdClass();
    $art->$nsArticleID = $article->getArticleID();
    $art->$nsProperties = $article->getArticleProperty;
    $art->$nsQuantity = 1;
    $art = new SoapVar($art, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);                
    $orderItems[] = $art;
    }
    $xml->$nsRequest->$nsItems = $orderItems;
```

I got this XML :

```
<ns2:Items>
   <SOAP-ENC:Struct>
       <ns2:ArticleID>242</ns2:ArticleID>
       <ns2:Properties/>
       <ns2:Quantity>1</ns2:Quantity>
   </SOAP-ENC:Struct>
   <SOAP-ENC:Struct>
        <ns2:ArticleID>1256</ns2:ArticleID>
        <ns2:Properties/>
        <ns2:Quantity>1</ns2:Quantity>
   </SOAP-ENC:Struct>
</ns2:Items>
```

How can I change the SOAP-ENC:Struct tag to ns2:OrderItem

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: Set the third parameter of the SoapVar to the name of your class

The long answer:

Create a container class OrderItem (I use here your coding style with the first capital letter, but this is not a good practice):

```
class OrderItem
{
   /**
    * @var int
   */
   public $ArticleID;

   /**
    * I use a string just for test purpose
    * @var string
   */
   public $Properties;

   /**
    * @var int
   */
   public $Quantity;
}

...
$art = new SoapVar($art, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, "OrderItem");
...
```

Without setting a third parameter the php Soap implementation does not know how the object should be named.

I have discovered you don't really need a container. It's enough to set a third param of the SoapVar to a desired name, e.g. OrderItem.

Comment: Can that be removed instead of set to something else? :)